# Split SSH-style user@domain/path?

Tags: python, url, ssh, rsync

I have URLs like the ones we enter in `ssh` / `rsync`:

```
s1 = 'user1@1.2.3.4/home/test/blabla'
s2 = 'user2@example.com/home/test/blabla'
```

**Is this a reliable way to get the user, domain, path, working for all kind of URLs:**

```
user = s1.split('@')[0]
domain = s1.split('@')[1].split('/')[0]
path = s1.split('@')[1].split('/')[1]
```

or is there a better way, included in the Python standard library?

Note: there seems to be different standardizations, see [URL format for ssh://](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/pipermail/mercurial-devel/2013-June/051583.html).

Comment: The problem that I see is `path` -- Since `path = s1.split('@')[1].split('/')[1]` would give you just `home` or `test` correct?  So maybe split it without the key. `path = s1.split('@')[1].split('/')` Roll back through the array `path` and re-create the path `for x in path: y = y + '/' + x` or something thereabouts -- Of course having to skip the first iteration, since that would be `user@example.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, the split on `@` does not allow for a second `@` in the path. And the path split does not include all the subdirectories.

Regular expressions are more powerful, and *can* be easier to understand that the detailed splits. They can capture with `()` into groups each part easily:

```py
user, domain, path = re.match(r"([^@]+)@([^/]+)(/.*)", s1).groups()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use regular expressions:

```py
import re

s1 = 'user1@1.2.3.4/home/test/blabla'

user = re.search(r'^(.+?)(?=\@)', s1).group()
domain = re.search(r'(?<=\@)(.+?)(?=\/)', s1).group()
path = re.search(r'/(.+?)$', s1).group()

print(user)    # user1
print(domain)  # 1.2.3.4
print(path)    # /home/test/blabla
```